# Python - read all files in a directory, and multiply the value in a specific line

Tags: python

What I need is simple:

- Read all the files in a dir.
- Multiply the value in a specific line (it's always the same in each file) with a specified multiplier.
- Write the result overwriting the value in that specific line.

```
    import os
    multiplier = input("Specify multiplier: ")
    directory = os.scandir('C:/Users/MP7/Desktop/PYTHON/LDT')
    os.chdir('C:/Users/MP7/Desktop/PYTHON/LDT')
    for file in directory:
        open_file = open(file,'r')
        read_file = open_file.read()
        content = file.readline()
        new_value = float(content[28]) * float(multiplier)
        write_file = open(file, 'w')
        write_file.write(read_file)
```

Comment: What does the specific line look like when you read it in ? i.e. is it just a number or is it text and a number ?? an example of the line would be useful. And which line number in the file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,  it would make us more easier to help you if you provide more details like, a example or demo, or error code.

Comment: Did something go wrong? Post any error messages.

Comment: As Scott mentioned, it's pretty much impossible to know where you've gone wrong without more details. What do the file contents look like? Where are you stuck? Are you receiving an Error message? If so, What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that directory is not a list of strings but a list of DirEntry, so you have to access the name property. Also it is a good practice to close files specially if you are going to operate on them, else you can open them in 'r+' for read and write.

You can use contexts so the file closes automatically when out of scope

```py
import os

multiplier = input("Specify multiplier: ")
directory = os.scandir('C:/Users/MP7/Desktop/PYTHON/LDT')
os.chdir('C:/Users/MP7/Desktop/PYTHON/LDT')
for file in directory:
    with open(file.name,'r') as open_file:
        content = open_file.readlines()
        print(content)
        content[1] = f'{str(float(content[1]) * float(multiplier))}\n'
    with open(file.name, 'w') as write_file:    
        write_file.writelines(content)
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you Rami, learned something.